# Could my api+serializer code be improved?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have 10 models(Urls1, Urls2, Urls3...)

Each looking like this:

```
class Url1(models.Model):

    keyword = models.ForeignKey(KW)
    url = models.URLField()
    pda = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    upa = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
```

My function uses moz api to pull PDA/UPA results in for 'url' field.

Here is function for first 2(rest 8 are the same):
**Whithout looking at entire code, second half is identical to first half with just names adjusted for second model**

```
def mozs():
    getids1 = Url1.objects.values_list('id', flat=True)    

    for id in getids1:

        if Url1.objects.get(id=id).pda == None:            
            a1 = Url1.objects.get(id=id).url          
            authorities = l.urlMetrics([a1], lsapi.UMCols.domainAuthority | lsapi.UMCols.pageAuthority)
            authorities =  str(authorities)
            authorities = authorities.translate(None, '[]')
            authorities = ast.literal_eval(authorities)
            authorities['keyword'] = id



            serializer = MozSerializer(data=authorities)

            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()  

            print "For %d we added %s" % (id, authorities)
            print type(authorities)

    getids2 = Url2.objects.values_list('id', flat=True)    

    for id in getids2:

        if Url2.objects.get(id=id).pda == None:            
            a2 = Url2.objects.get(id=id).url          
            authorities = l.urlMetrics([a2], lsapi.UMCols.domainAuthority | lsapi.UMCols.pageAuthority)
            authorities =  str(authorities)
            authorities = authorities.translate(None, '[]')
            authorities = ast.literal_eval(authorities)
            authorities['keyword'] = id    


            serializer = MozSerializer2(data=authorities)

            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()  

            print "For %d we added %s" % (id, authorities)
            print type(authorities)
```

And serializer(the same thing after half):

```
class MozSerializer(serializers.Serializer):    
    keyword = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Url1.objects.all())
    pda = serializers.FloatField()
    upa = serializers.FloatField() 


    def save(self):
        keyword = self.validated_data['keyword']
        pda = self.validated_data['pda']
        upa = self.validated_data['upa']

        Url1.objects.update(pda=pda, upa=upa)

class MozSerializer2(serializers.Serializer):    
    keyword = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Url2.objects.all())
    pda = serializers.FloatField()
    upa = serializers.FloatField() 


    def save(self):
        keyword = self.validated_data['keyword']
        pda = self.validated_data['pda']
        upa = self.validated_data['upa']

        Url2.objects.update(pda=pda, upa=upa)
```

This is my first django project so it's probably full of stupid stuff - Any improvement suggestions are welcome :)

Comment: What does this line `l.urlMetrics([a1], lsapi.UMCols.domainAuthority | lsapi.UMCols.pageAuthority)` returns?

Comment: [{'keyword': 59, u'pda': 100, u'upa': 1}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you need 10 identical tables, let's assume you have a good reason and just try to improve what you have. Why not just pass the model reference to methods so you don't need to duplicate code just to change the model? Seems like you can accomplish the same thing with just the code below and if you need to change it you can change it in one place.

*Disclaimer: I am not familiar with the moz api and this code is not tested. There may be a problem with the `__init__()` method of `MozSerializer` such as missing params from the parent but at a minimum the `mozs()` and `moz()` methods should be sound.

```
def mozs():

    models = [Url1, Url2, Url3, Url4, Url5, Url6, Url7, Url8, Url9, Url10]

    for model in models:
        moz(model)

def moz(model):

    getids = model.objects.values_list('id', flat=True)

    for id in getids:

        if model.objects.get(id=id).pda == None:
            a2 = model.objects.get(id=id).url
            authorities = l.urlMetrics([a2], lsapi.UMCols.domainAuthority | lsapi.UMCols.pageAuthority)
            authorities =  str(authorities)
            authorities = authorities.translate(None, '[]')
            authorities = ast.literal_eval(authorities)
            authorities['keyword'] = id

            serializer = MozSerializer(data=authorities, model=model)

            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()

            print "For %d we added %s" % (id, authorities)
            print type(authorities)

class MozSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    pda = serializers.FloatField()
    upa = serializers.FloatField()

    def __init__(self, data=None, model=model):
        self.model = model
        self.keyword = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=model.objects.all())
        super(MozSerializer, self).__init__(data=data)

    def save(self):
        keyword = self.validated_data['keyword']
        pda = self.validated_data['pda']
        upa = self.validated_data['upa']

        self.model.objects.update(pda=pda, upa=upa)
```

Comment: Just wanted to drop a thanks man, this saved me a lot of code :)

Comment: My pleasure, glad I could help.